# DHCP client doesn't have internet but can ping gateway

Tags: networking

I have two virtual machines (host machine is on Windows):

- One DHCP server(on Debian)
- One Client(on Debian)

The problem is that the client receives an IP address and both machines can ping each other, but the client cannot access internet. *(ping 8.8.8.8 never returns)*

- My DHCP server is connected to Internet through "enp0s3" in **NAT**.
- My DHCP server is connected in **Host-Only** through "enp0s9".
- My Client is connected in **Host-Only** through "enp0s3".

Am I wrong in the network types that I chose?

`ifconfig -a` on the DHCP server :

[image: <code>ifconfig -a</code> on the DHCP server]

`ifconfig -a && ip route show` on the client : 
[image: if config -a && ip route show on the client]

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` :
   [image: dhcpd.conf]

I deactivated Windows's firewall and iptables --flush on Debian. In the future I would like to replace the virtual machine client by a real machine plugged in on the Ethernet.

I give my client an IP address, a mask, a gateway. I think it is a gateway problem, but I don't know what to do to get Internet, on the client.

Comment: Besides NAT... Is ip forwarding enabled on the server? What is routing table for the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable ip forwarding and use iptables to forward outgoing traffic from enp0s9 to enp0s3

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

#
# delete all existing rules.
#
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

# Always accept loopback traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT


# Allow established connections, and those not coming from the outside
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i ! enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s9 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing connections from the LAN side.
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s9 -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE

# Don't forward from the outside to the inside.
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s3 -j REJECT

# Enable routing.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Source: https://debian-administration.org/article/23/Setting_up_a_simple_Debian_gateway

Comment: I changed the line iptables      -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i ! enp0s3 -j ACCEPT to iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i enp0s3 -j ACCEPT (I removed the exclamation mark)
That works ! Thanks !